# How to open generated pdf (with laravel snappy) in new tab using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, pdf

I am using AJAX to return html that my laravel controller transforms to pdf (because of some calculations done by js).
Then, I need to open the generated pdf in new tab, after saving it in my folder.
I do not want to use storage/public folder. because there are other private folders under storage directory, I am saving in. So I could not get their link with laravel.

In my controller, I have:

```
    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($pdf_html)->setPaper('A4')->setOption('header-html', $header)->save($filepath.$filename);

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline',
    ];

    return Response::make(file_get_contents($filepath.$filename), 200, $headers);
```

My js:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/generatepdf',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
                    /*What to do here?*/ 
        }
```

I got:
[image: DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Unable to open a window with invalid URL]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't return a Response in your function, instead return the filename of the saved pdf (include the folder name if it is exclusive to this pdf).
Then open that url with the Ajax callback.

```
success: function(data){
    window.open('pdf/'+data, '_blank');
}
```

Because you save your PDF in the storage folder, you will need a route and a handler.

```
Route::get('pdf/{filename}', 'SomeController@getPdf');
```

In your controller:

```
public function getPDF($filename){
    (maybe add some code to check if user is authorized)
    return response()->download(storage_path('path-to-pdf-folder'.$filename), null, [], null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Could you help please about images to show on page before sending all html via ajax? I do not know how to make them shown. thanks in advance

Comment: I have some images to show on page. The images must be shown on generated pdf too. but they are inside private folders. I need to show them on my php page, then get dom and send by ajax. The pdf is generated now but images not shown yet